# python - Plot Precision Recall Curve for different multi-class classifiers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have predicted output for validation data which is single label multi-class classifier. I have run multiple classifiers. I want to plot the PR curves for each of them in a single plot. I am not able to do that. Any pointers?

```
For a single classifier, the dataframe with results look like this : 

label   predictedAns    predictedProb
1       2                 0.999281
2       2                 0.999754
2       2                 0.999754
3       3                 0.999762
2       2                 0.999641
2       2                 0.999641
2       2                 0.9996
```

Comment: Can you show an expected result? because you can't plot curve for a classifier when you only have you'r recall/precision value for the last epoch, you'll only get two value (precision and recall) for each classifier

Answer (score 1):

You can seperately calculate metrics you want to observe for different cutoffs, and then refer to [this page](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/) later on. Plotly comes with handy notebook integration, as interactive plots. You can add different lines with "add_trace" method which you can find it on the page, and observe all of them in a single interactive plot.